# What happen on current viewController when i call presentModalViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

i'm developing an app for iphone, and i use

```
[self presentModalViewController:aViewControllerInitializateBefore animated:YES];
```

Can you tell me what happens to the current viewController when i use this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current view controller stays "underneath" the modal view controller and will reappear when you call

```
- (void)dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
```

either on the modal view or the parent/presenting view controller (as the parent/presenting view controller's view is no longer visible, it's view may be unloaded when the system requires memory, and reloaded on dismiss).

From this method's documentation:

> The parent view controller is responsible for dismissing the modal
>   view controller it presented using the
>   presentModalViewController:animated: method. If you call this method
>   on the modal view controller itself, however, the modal view
>   controller automatically forwards the message to its parent view
>   controller.
>
> If you present several modal view controllers in succession, and thus
>   build a stack of modal view controllers, calling this method on a view
>   controller lower in the stack dismisses its immediate child view
>   controller and all view controllers above that child on the stack.
>   When this happens, only the top-most view is dismissed in an animated
>   fashion; any intermediate view controllers are simply removed from the
>   stack. The top-most view is dismissed using its modal transition
>   style, which may differ from the styles used by other view controllers
>   lower in the stack.

Also note the change in iOS 5

> Prior to iOS 5.0, if a view did not have a parent view controller and
>   was being presented modally, the view controller that was presenting
>   it would be returned. This is no longer the case. You can get the
>   presenting view controller using the presentingViewController
>   property.

Comment: understood! Thanks! Can you tell me a way to load dynamically uiviewcontroller without the duty to come back to the view that called the current? :) i hope to have formed as well the answer

Comment: You have no "duty" to get back to current, you can just never call the dismiss method. Or you can use a UINavigationController to push/pop UIViewControllers (there are a few tutorials on this if you look them up in google).

Comment: if i don't call dismiss.. and i use always presentmodalviewcontroller to change from uiviewcontroller is correct? without anytime call dismiss

Comment: It's better to use UINavigationController to deal with UIViewController hierarchies but you can also stack modal view controllers on top of each other.

Comment: The problem is that my app is not a navigation's view based application, but i have some viewcontroller to show dinamically EX:         Main->View1 or View 2. from one of these -> View 3->View 4 or View5 or View 6. From View 6 -> go View 1. From View 4 go to View 2 etc... Which kind of application is this? what can i use?

Comment: You can use a UINavigationController and hide the navigation bar and without the navigation animations, if you need to go from View6 straight back to view1 then you can use the UINavigationController method popToViewController: